# 17.10 auto login issue

Tags: drivers, xorg, 17.10, nvidia-geforce, auto-login

I just installed 17.10 in a new build and I noticed  I am unable to have auto login work.

I  went to settings>user and changed the toggle to (ON) and enable auto login. However after a reboot my password is required and the setting is toggled back to off.

However, under software & updates> additional drivers. I have the option of choosing either "X.Org X Server" driver or NVIDIA binary" driver. When I choose the 'X.Org X" option there is no issue but there is an issue with the NVIDIA driver.

I am not sure what role the drivers play. Any help would be great.

I guess I would like to also know which driver I should be running anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I would like to also know which driver I should be running anyway.

The one that works best for you... And that includes license concerns.

- If you do not game on Ubuntu the generic one is more than enough to have a working system and there is not really a need for the 3rd party version.
- If you do not want to have drivers open source community has no control over don't use the 3rd party driver.

> I am unable to have auto login work.

As stated during install: using encryption will disable auto login.

> However, under software & updates> additional drivers. I have the option of choosing either "X.Org X Server" driver or NVIDIA binary" driver. When I choose the 'X.Org X" option there is no issue but there is an issue with the NVIDIA driver.

That could be a bug. Problem: the nvidia driver the community has no control over so there probably is no fix if it is a bug.

- install the 3rd party driver. Set auto login to on. Close the user window and check if the setting sticks before you reboot.
- Check .xsession-errors in /home/$USER/ for error notices about auto login.
- Check /var/log/  with `ls -ltr` and see if the log that was last changed has a notice about auto login.

If there is anything edit your question to add the information.